# Linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Is there a linear bounded (continuous) operator T from $c$ (convergent sequences with sup norm) ONTO $l^1$ (with its usual norm)?

If it were so (which seems not), using the open mapping theorem we get T is open. Would this mean $l^1$ is isomorphic to some subspace of $c$? In any case, I don't know how to conclude.

Any help or hints will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously $c=c_0\oplus_1\mathbb{C}$. Assume you have quotient map $c\twoheadrightarrow l_1$ (which is open by open mapping theorem). Applying $^*$ functor you get inclusion $l_1^*\hookrightarrow c^*$, which is bounded below. Since $l_1^*=l_\infty$ and $c^*=(c_0\oplus_1\mathbb{C})^*=(c_0)^*\oplus_\infty\mathbb{C}^*=l_1\oplus_\infty\mathbb{C}$ you get inclusion of non separable space $\ell_\infty$ into seprable space $l_1\oplus_\infty\mathbb{C}$. This is impossible, so we get contradiction.

Comment: +1, but maybe we should add that it is important that the map $c\to l^1$ would be open, so that the dual map $l^\infty\to l^1$ would be bounded below. The point being that it is easy to find an injective map from $l^\infty$ to $l^1$, namely $(x_n)\mapsto(x_n/n^2)$.

Comment: Thanks @HaraldHanche-Olsen I will add this to the answer.